# Dado un texto y una letra indique cuantas palabras aparecen que contengan esa letra

Tags: python, string, lista

estaba realizando este ejercicio, sin embargo, al ejecutarlo no me aparece el numero de palabras que contienen tal letra, sólo aparece un cero, ¿ en que estoy mal? De antemano muchas gracias

```
texto=raw_input("ingrese un texto: ")
letra=raw_input("ingrese una letra: ")
contador=0
textoLista=texto.split()
for palabra in textoLista:
    for caracter in palabra:
        if letra in caracter==True:
            contador=contador+1
print contador
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar dos for anidados es inecesario y muy ineficiente, con un solo for e `in` hacemos lo mismo pero con menos recursos y más 'pythónico':

```
texto=raw_input("ingrese un texto: ")
letra=raw_input("ingrese una letra: ")

contador = 0
for palabra in texto.split():
    if letra in palabra:
        contador  += 1
print contador
```

Otra solución algo más eficiente y con menos código es usar un generador y la función preconstruida `sum`:

```
texto=raw_input("ingrese un texto: ")
letra=raw_input("ingrese una letra: ")
print(sum(letra in palabra for palabra in texto.split()))
```

La comparativa usando un texto de 80000000 palabras (en mi caso particular y bajo Python 2.7):

> 2 ciclos for e igualdad: 49.6679999828 segundos.
>   sum y generador: 16.3229999542 segundos.
>   1 ciclo for e in: 13.4120001793 segundos.

**P.D : Tu código falla por el orden de evaluación de tu sentencia `if`**, tu línea es:

```
if letra in caracter==True:
```

Podría parecer que lo que hace esto es evaluar `letra in caracter` (que retorna `False` o `True`) y luego mira si el resultado es `True`. Pero el problema es que esto no es lo que pasa, primero se evalua la igualdad (`==` y luego el `in`). Imaginemos lo siguiente:

```
if 'a' in 'a' == True:
    print 'Si'
```

Si lo ejecutamos no imprime nada, el problema es que primero se hace:

```
'a' == True
```

Esto lógicamente es `False`, el resto ya no tiene sentido por lo que el `if` retorna `False`. Para solucionarlo podemos añadir un paréntesis para que evalue en el orden que queremos:

```
if ('a' in 'a') == True:
    print 'Si'
```

En tu caso sería:

```
if (letra in caracter) == True:
    contador=contador+1
```

Pero esto es redundancia, en Python bastaría:

```
if letra in caracter:
    contador=contador+1
```

Pero recuerda que esto contaría todas las letras iguales a la introducida  presentes en la frase y no las palabras que contienen la letra, la solución es eliminar el segundo `for` como te comenté anteriormente.

Comment: wow muchisimas gracias amigo. Tu respuesta está muy completa y precisamente es lo que buscaba: un programa que utilizara funciones básicas . Muchas gracias por haberte dado el tiempo de responderme y a la vez explicarme el error de mi programa. Ahora sí que se despejaron todas mis dudas y a la vez, se respondieron todas mis necesidades, muchas gracias y saludos!!

Comment: pero sabes, me quedó una duda. Por qué sólo basta usar un solo for-in?? Se supone que al utilizar solo un for-in, se recorrería solamente las palabras y no las letras presentes en cada palabra, no entiendoo :( , ¿ explicame por favor? Por cierto, probé tu programa y funciona perfectamente, pero es que me quedó dando vueltas esa duda del for-in. Saludos

Comment: @WhiteMamba como bien dices con un solo `for` iteras sobre las palabras. Lo que ocurre realmente es que la claúsula`in` actua como un segundo `for` y es ella la que itera (eficientemente) sobre cada palabra.  Esto es muy genérico, la realidad interna es más compleja pero básicamente `a in b` lo que hace es comprobar si `a` es miembro del objeto `b`. En el caso de cadenas retorna `True` si y solo si `a` es una **subcadena** de `b`. Coloquialmente podemos decir que `in`  lo que hace es preguntar : ¿Está `a` dentro de `b`?

Comment: @WhiteMamba no se si te habré dejado medianamente claro como funciona, te dejo la documentación oficial sobre el operador `in`en el siguiente [enlace](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) por si quieres echarle un ojo.

Comment: Dejame ver si entendí, el primer for-in permite iterar sobre las palabras del texto, luego el in que incluyes dentro del ciclo permite iterar sobre las LETRAS de cada palabra ? O en ningun momento se itera sobre las letras?? Jajaja parece que me confundí

Comment: @WhiteMamba no estas confundido, el `in` se encarga de iterar sobre cada letra de cada palabra. La realidad es algo más compleja ya que actua de fiorma diferente dependiendo del objeto con el que trabaje, es decir, el algoritmo que usa es diferente para una lista, una cadena o un diccionario. Pero en esencia el `in` lo que hace es iterar sobre cada carácter y retornar si la letra está o no en esa palabra.Es equivalente a `any(letra is caracter or letra == caracter for caracter in palabra)`.Por cierto otra forma alternativa sería usar el método `find` de los strings: `palabra.find(letra) != -1`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ! Ahora si que me quedó todo muy claro, en serio te agradezco mucho toda la ayuda y tiempo que le has brindado a mi problema . Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

Tu último `if` está mal formado porque mezclas la sintaxis del `for in` con la sintaxis del `if`, deberías comparar si `palabra` y  `caracter` son iguales, así:

```
texto=raw_input("ingrese un texto: ")
letra=raw_input("ingrese una letra: ")

contador=0
textoLista=texto.split()

for palabra in textoLista:
    for caracter in palabra:
        if letra == caracter:
            contador=contador+1
            break
print contador
```

Nota que la línea que cambia es esta:

```
if letra == caracter:
```

Y añadimos un `break` para que abandone la palabra si ya hemos encontrado la letra que buscábamos en ella.

Ahora, como mencionas en los comentarios, si deseas evitar el uso de un `break`, entonces deberás usar una variable auxiliar, así (nota la variable `encontrado`):

```
texto=raw_input("ingrese un texto: ")
letra=raw_input("ingrese una letra: ")

contador=0
textoLista=texto.split()

for palabra in textoLista:
    encontrado = False
    for caracter in palabra:
        if (letra == caracter and encontrado == False):
            contador=contador+1
            encontrado = True

print contador
```

Sin embargo, no recomiendo esta segunda solución porque es más lenta. Tiene que recorrer todas las letras de cada palabra aunque ya hayas encontrado lo que buscas.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda, ese break cumple con el objetivo  de mi programa :D . Sin embargo, tengo dos preguntas mal.

¿ Por qué mi if está mal ? Por qué mi contador no cuenta la cantidad de palabras que contienen la letra elegida?? 

Mi otra pregunta es: ¿ existe una alternativa que no utilice el break como funcion?? Digamos, que utilice funciones más basicas? Es que a veces no me permiten usar ciertas funciones ni metodos :(

Comment: Fue sin querer @Mariano, tuve que eliminar una de las dos.

Comment: @WhiteMamba ya he puesto la razón por la que tu `if` estaba malo, déjame ver si encuentro una forma de no usar `break` y lo agrego a la respuesta. Aunque ahora mismo no se me ocurre nada más básico que un `break`, eso está bastante cerca del lenguaje máquina.

Comment: vale muchas gracias, estare atento a tu respuesta

Comment: @WhiteMamba he agregado una segunda solución que no hace uso del `break`, espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvio muchisimo tu segunda solucion . Saludos y gracias por dedicarle tiempo a mi consulta :D